# jquery sharing method between onclick and onload

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'd like to learn how to better write a more generic method which can be called onload and onclick. This is what I have thus far which works perfectly.

```
rushJustification($("#rush"));

$("input#rush").click(function() {
    rushJustification($(this));
});

function rushJustification(obj) {
    var rushInput = obj.is(':checked');
    var rushContainer = $("#rush-justification-container");

    if(rushInput) {
       rushContainer.slideDown(300);
    } else {
       rushContainer.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of copying the contents of the `click` handler, trigger it as well:

```
$("input#rush").click(function() {
    rushJustification($(this));
}).click();
```

The previously mentioned method can have some side effects, when other scripts have already bound an event. In your case, you can then use the following code:

```
rushJustification( $("input#rush").click(function() {
    rushJustification($(this));
}) );
```

It may look weird at first. This feature is possible, because of jQuery's chainability. The `click` method returns the same jQuery collection, namely `$('input#rush')`. This is then passed as an argument to the `rushJustification` function.

Comment: This approach appears to have some unexpected behavior when using it with ui-checkbox. When the checkbox has been saved :checked, the page reloads checkbox unchecked and rushContainer displayed block.

Comment: @George I'm not sure what you're talking about. Do you have multiple `click` events bound to `#rush`?

Comment: I see what's happening, I have a checkbox on my page that is populated by the backend. If true, I need to display a textfield. Your code is firing the event handler every time the page loads which reverses the checkbox rather than just calling the rushJustification method without the click. This is the cleanest i've been able to get the code     rushJustification();
    $("input#rush").click(rushJustification);

Comment: Rob, that worked perfectly. At least now I know how to clean up a lot of my code. Thank you very much!